# time and distance

Tags: recreational-mathematics, contest-math

Dexter and Prexter are competing with each other in a friendly community competition in a pool of 50m length and the race is for 1000m. Dexter crosses 50m in 2 min and Prexter in 3 min 15 sec. Each time they meet/cross each other, they do handshake's. How many such handshake's will happen if they start from the same end at the same time?
A.18
B.19
C.20
D.17

how to approach these types of questions ? please explain with well solution.
[here is the reference link](http://www.lofoya.com/Aptitude-Questions-And-Answers/Time-Speed-and-Distance/l2p8.htm) - see Question 36.

Comment: Did you try use two trigonometric functions?

Comment: Isn't it $19$ times (all laps except for the first lap), regardless of their speeds? Unless "cross each other" means "cross in front of each other" (i.e., swimming in opposite directions).

Comment: @DiegoMath no i haven't use trignometric functions . Can you tell me how ?

Comment: @TanishGupta look the Bananarama's answer, it's better.

Comment: barakmanos yes its 19 .Please explain it how ?

Answer (score 1):

Total race = **1000m**
Length of pool = **50m**
To complete **1000m** one has to complete **20 rounds** of **50** each.
They will meet at the same side only at **26th round** as **2 & 3.25** LCM is **26** but we know race ends after **20** rounds.
So they will meet at each round except the first as they are starting from the same side and Dexter will take an early lead.
**20-1 = 19**

Answer (score 0):

Firs off: notice the race lasts 40 minutes.

Note Dexter and Prexter are only simultaneously at the edge of the pool at minute 26. Since Dexter is at the edge after an even amount of minutes and Prexter is at the edge after a multiple of $3.25$ minutes, the only even multiple of $3.25$ under  $40$ is $26$. So they are only at the edge at the same time at minute 26. However they are at opposite edges, since $2*13=26=3.25*8$ and $13$ is odd while $8$ is even. Thus the number of handshakes in an edge is 0.

Since the only time both Dexter and Prexter cross the lap at the same time is at the start this means each time Dexter crosses the pool after the first time he will cross Prexter and shake his hand, Dexter does this 19, thus the answer is 19.

Comment: @banarama answer given in the link is 19 times and please explain me mathematically as i am still in doubt.

Comment: Oh, they are right, because at minute 26 they are both at the edge, but at different edges, so they never shake hands at the edge. That means the answer is indeed 19.